# How can I change the width of Markdown cell previews in Notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Is there any way in vs code to control the width of markdown cell for notebooks? Sometimes it may be too hard to read long lines. There is an example below.

[image]

It will be greate if markdown cell looks like on the image bellow. I just split the tab and comfirm the width of the tab manually but it will be great if I could manually set the width of the markdown text. It is more convinient for reading a big notebooks.

[image]

Comment: Please give more context for the problem. It seems like you intend to use a Jupyter notebook to display some rendered Markdown. I can't understand why VS Code could possibly have anything to do with that. Surely, the width either depends on something *that the Python code does*, or else on a configuration setting *of the notebook*.

Comment: I have updated the question. May be it became more informative.

Comment: If it's helpful, I googled "jupyter limit width of markdown" and found this: [How to modify the line width of ipython notebook markdown cell](/q/30693288/4518341) and based on the answer googled "vscode jupyter css" and found this: [provide option to use custom css files for notebook - GitHub microsoft/vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12862)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I founded the first link before I had potsted the question but I can't understand how to do it in vs code and answered here.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't understand, you can get some mileage of creating a dummy cell with the following content:

```html
%%html
<style>
div {
    width: 50ch !important; /* or whatever width in whatever CSS units you want */
}
</style>
```

You have to run that cell for it to take effect.

It's not perfect. Things like code blocks won't get overflow scrollbars. There might be a way to get that back, but I'm not invested enough to investigate further.

Inspired by [this answer post](/a/76313891/11107541).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is helpful anyway! But how I understand vs code can't provide this options in its settings, isn't it?

Comment: Is there any way to set with for text and another width for images?